# PhP/Login empty input box issue

Tags: php

I'm creating a website that requires the user to enter a username and password to access the site. 
Everything works perfectly. If right password and username are entered, access is granted. If not, it redirects the user to the same login form page. 
However, the problem i'm facing is in the following code in php:

```
 if (!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pw'] ) {

        die("At least one box was left empty");

    }
```

This piece of code checks if the user left any of the 2 input boxes empty. It kills the site and outputs the wanted sentence. However, what i would like to do is redirect the user into the Login form page.
Any help with that? 
Thanks folks

Answer (score 1):

You haven't even tried to redirect.

Use `header("Location: login.php");` (with whatever the location of your login page is, if it's not `login.php`), then `exit`.

Comment: In fact i have tried             header("Location: login.php");      but for some reason it doesnt work. It just logs in as if the password and username were properly entered.

Comment: Remember, header() can be used only if you do not echo/print text before calling it.

Answer (score 1):

WRONG:

```
   if (!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pw'] ) {
```

Wrong syntax in your example, you need to add one sign to make it correct:

CORRECT:

```
   if (!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['pw'] ) {
                            ^
```

Comment: No, you need two, but there is one in your example!

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

- Use the header()-function: `header('Location: login.php');`
- Echo/ Print a java-script tag: `echo "<script language="javascript">window.location.href='login.php';</script>`

The `header()`-function can only be used, if you do not output some text before you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **empty** and **header** functions !

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['username']) OR empty($_POST['pw']))
{
    header('Location: pathtoyourloginpage.php');
}

else
{
    echo "OK";
}
?>
```

*empty* check if $_POST['username'] and $_POST['pw'] are empty. If it so they return TRUE else FALSE.

*OR* is a logical operator, you'll found more infos here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

**More informations about empty(); and header();**

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.empty.php

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to use double `|` to compare, the correct way is: `value || value`

Redirect to the login using `header('Location: login.php');`

If you prefer to show an extra message in the login form with the error, you can do something like this: `header('Location: login.php?error=1');`

Then, in the `login.php` you can check for `$_GET['error']`, doing the following:

```
if($_GET['error'] == 1){
     echo "You have to fill username and password in order to continue.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to solve your problem:

You need to declare this variable first, in your core.php file, for example and use it in all your php files, or just declare it in the file you are working on:

```
$current_file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

Then simply use it in the header() function:

```
header('Location: '.$current_file);
```

The opportunity in this method is that you use a universal variable to specify the url in the header function or in any other function.